# clearinterval not working when hover over

Tags: javascript, clearinterval

I follow all the answers I got for the clearinterval, it exactly the same as how others working one. Not sure what I did wrong. I just want the slide to stop when to hover over to the div. I even put a cursor: pointer into the div, but seem like this doesn't help.

```js
var myVar = window.setInterval(yanslider, 7000);
  
  function yanslider(){
    $('.slider-inner > div:first')
      .fadeOut(1000)
      .removeClass('active')
      .next()
      .fadeIn(1000)
      .addClass('active')
      .end()
      .appendTo('.slider-inner');
  }

  $( ".slider-inner" ).hover(function() {
      // onmouseover
      window.clearInterval(myVar);
      // onmouseout
      yanslider();
  });
```

```css
.slider-inner{
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
 position:relative;
 overflow:hidden;
 border:#666 solid 1px;
}

.slider-inner > div{
 display:none;
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
}

.slider-inner .active{
 display:inline-block;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider-inner">
          <div id="item" class="active"><p>#1</p></div>
          <div id="item" ><p>#2</p></div>
          <div id="item" ><p>#3</p></div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach to this is to use a timeout, rather than an interval.

- `yanslider` can create a timeout that performs the action, and recursively calls itself to create a logical loop
- on page load, call `yanslider()` to start the loop
- When you hover over the slider, cancel the timeout
- When you hover out the slider, call the function again so that the logical loop resumes

```js
var sliderTimeout;

function yanslider () {
  //start a timeout for seven seconds later
  sliderTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
    $('.slider-inner > div:first')
        .fadeOut(1000)
        .removeClass('active')
        .next()
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .addClass('active')
        .end()
        .appendTo('.slider-inner');
        
        yanslider(); // recursive loop
  }, 2000);
}

$( ".slider-inner" ).hover(
  function () { // onmouseover
    clearInterval( sliderTimeout ); // terminate the timeout
  },
  function () { // onmouseout
    yanslider(); // start the loop again
  }
);

yanslider(); // start the loop on page load
```

```css
.slider-inner{
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
 position:relative;
 overflow:hidden;
 border:#666 solid 1px;
}

.slider-inner > div{
 display:none;
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
}

.slider-inner .active{
 display:inline-block;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider-inner">
          <div id="item" class="active"><p>#1</p></div>
          <div id="item" ><p>#2</p></div>
          <div id="item" ><p>#3</p></div>
        </div>
```